# What happened to Amy in The Equalizer 2 (2018)?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-equalizer-2

I never understood what really happened to Amy, the girl who was taken to the [*Massachusetts General Hospital*](https://youtu.be/jyI5wgItJKM?t=121) by McCall.

[The Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Equalizer_2#Plot) says that she was assaulted. If so, why?

Was she raped?

Comment: The movie tells us enough to know McCall rescued her from her abusers (and punished them). It does so economically and It doesn't need to tell us any more. The story illustrates his character and capability efficiently; any further exposition would dilute that point. As would details about what happened to her.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's never clearly said. Not in the movie, not in the script. The closest you can get (guess) is that Amy is victim of drugs and sexual assault. The punks that "*invited*" her to their party are under influence (pills, cocaine, alcohol) and took what they wanted from her, whether she agreed or not. Looking at her face, pain and cries in the car, I'm sure it was **not** what she would have expected from a party between colleagues. As an intern (as Amy), you expect to hang out and have fun with colleagues sometimes, but not *that kind* of party.

> But not tonight. Tonight I'm gonna need your cameras, cell phones...
>
> ...anything you might have used to record **what you did to her**. (emphasis mine)

When she gets into the car, you see her face, she is shocked, her hair is messy, her clothes are put in such a way that she's scruffy, she looks sick, she shows pain.

All these signs are the result of what is probably a sexual assault with drugs. As said in the script:

> McCall: Took her to Mass General. They're pumping her stomach as we speak.

Source: [the equalizer 2](https://subslikescript.com/movie/The_Equalizer_2-3766354)